# Closing connection when using Azure JS SDK for Service Bus is needed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, connection, connection-pooling, azure-sdk

Is there any downside if in my server-side app, each time, usually one or a few times per incoming HTTP request, I open a new connection `New ServiceBusClient(connStr)` and start using it and don't call `close` method at the end?

Could cause port or memory exhaustion or `New ServiceBusClient(connStr)` will use some kind of connection pooling underneath so no concern?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the [`close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusclient?view=azure-node-latest#close__) method at the end, otherwise it will cause the issues as you mentioned.

Also in the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions), it always does that.

```
async function main() {
const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
.....

} finally {
        await sbClient.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reference to your guess? I understand to would be safer to close it but the question is "must close" or "would be better/safer to close"?

Comment: @mehran No, but I think it is a normal thing we always do, and what you mean "must"? I think there is nothing we "must" do in the world, of course you could choose not to close it, but I think it will cause memory exhaustion. If we already have a better choice, why we consider a worse one?

Answer (score 0):

No there's no connection pooling. Each time an instance of `ServiceBusClient` is created, an underlying connection is created.  It's better to call `close()` when the client is no longer used.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/ab566082fd5182903cc2144efbbf3c197c3e6f6a/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/src/serviceBusClient.ts#L78-L96